# Rails 6 webpacker problem importing magnific-popup package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, magnific-popup

Im using rails 6 and webpacker.
Im trying to use a js lib called [magnific popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).

```
yarn add magnific-popup
```

It relies on jquery so I added to my environment.js :

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

the created a videoPopup.js file :

```
> import 'magnific-popup'
> 
> document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function (event) {  
> $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
>     disableOn: 700,
>     type: 'iframe',
>     mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
>     removalDelay: 160,
>     preloader: false,
> 
>     fixedContentPos: false   }); });
```

Then in application.js

```
require('./videoPopups')
```

In the browser I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function
```

$() (jquery) seems to be defined though and returns the html nodes.

What am I missing here ? How can I debug this ?